# I am performing the test case on iframe but the click event not displaying the result using protractor

Tags: angularjs, iframe, click, protractor, using

```
describe('Protractor iframe Test', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.get('my url');
    });
    it('should test the iframe', function(){
        //browser.switchTo().frame(0);
        browser.driver.switchTo().frame(
            browser.driver.findElement(
                protractor.By.xpath('//*[@id="right_frame_h"]')));
        // Test iframe with driver
        var blLink = browser.driver.findElement(
            protractor.By.xpath('//*[@id="category_link_BLAceServers"]'));
        // this click is not displaying out put.
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id("category_link_MLAceServers")).click();
        // giving result successfully 
        expect(blLink.getText()).toEqual('ProLiant BL Servers'); 
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you post your html code? Also try to put in sleep after clicking the element and before expecting or best way is to wait for the element `blLink` to be displayed using protractor wait - `browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(blLink), 10000)` and then try to use expect.

Comment: I see that you are calling "browser.driver" directly instead of using "element(by.id(''))", is the page inside of the iFrame a non-Angular site? If the page is an angular side I would recommend using Protractors syntax instead of the unwrapped Selenium syntax and see if that works for you. You can switch to the iFrame using either of the following code snippets: `browser.switchTo().frame(0);`  OR   `browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id('right_frame_h')));`

Comment: i see this same issue?